# A file or folder with the name already exists when unit test project added

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Large edit to make this more appropriate than "VS has a bug" complaint.

If I add a unit test project to my VS2012 solution, I can't add any item at all to any project in the solution.  VS complains that another file or folder with that name, whatever name I choose, already exists.  I also cannot add existing items to projects.

If I remove the unit test project, problem goes away.  Does anyone know about some dumb way I set up my solution to trigger this problem?

Comment: Maybe it is a permissions issue. Make sure you have write permissions to your solution folder?

Comment: The name "kjnksjadnga984gheufdnsfg.cs" is more common than you would think. Did you double-check that you did not add another class with that name? :-)

Comment: I have full control for the solution directory and all children.  This is my personal workstation and wasn't a problem yesterday.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the Solution, create a new one and import your projects?

Comment: If you navigate to the project in Windows Explorer, anything pop out at you that says 'this has gone wrong'?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: See edit -- if I remove the unit test project, problem goes away.  Add a new one, problem comes back, remove new one, problem goes away.  Neat!

Comment: I've seen VS2012 do weird things with various project types combined in one solution. You might want to file an issue on Connect, if the problem is easily reproducible and also happens without any plugins loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I am unable to reproduce this in VS2013, and VS2012 is totally old by now, I'll say an "acceptable" solution (hopefully not the only one) is to upgrade. Thanks everyone for your assistance.